# how to change inputFeild2 val when first inputFeild val change by jquery

Tags: jquery

hi guys i want to solve this problem i want inputFeild2 change by jquery when inputFeild1 Get the value back from jquery . i just want the event when the inputFeild1 get the value back from jquery

```
$("#inputFeild").change(function() {
//some code value returned to the form "inputFeild1"
}

<input type="text" name="inputFeild"  id="inputFeild" />
<input type="text" name="inputFeild1" id="inputFeild1" />
<input type="text" name="inputFeild2" id="inputFeild2" />
```

Comment: Please add some sort of code snippet or something for people to work off of other than what you have. This question will likely get down voted to oblivion without it. 

That said, event listeners are what you are looking for here. Consult the jQuery documentation for those.

Comment: sorry i hope this change clear what i want

Comment: @McGaz [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) works perfectly fine for input fields

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still pretty unclear but if you want inputFeild2 to have the same value as inputFeild1 then you can do this:

```js
$('#inputFeild1').change(function() {
    $('#inputFeild2').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Input feild 1: <input type="text" name="inputFeild1" id="inputFeild1">
Input feild 2: <input type="text" name="inputFeild2" id="inputFeild2">
```

Comment: that exactly what i want but the problem the change event dosnot apply when inputFeild1 get the value back from jquery cuz originally inputFeild1 get the value from jquery return

Comment: Get what value back? If you're setting the value of inputFeild1 using jQuery somewhere then you can always call `$('#inputFeild1').trigger('change')` to manually trigger a change event.

Comment: inputFeild1 value change when i change inputFeild by my self . i want inputFeild2 value change depending on inputFeild1 .i hope u get what i wanted and sorry iam not good in english

Comment: Did you try `.trigger('change')`?

Comment: i wish u can write the code cuz i am new to jquery :)

Comment: **The code is right there.** Please make an effort at trying to understand how to use jQuery instead of asking us to write all of the code.